# Odoo kanban "quick create" ("+") button to open "New task" form

Tags: python, forms, odoo, odoo-10, kanban

In Project tasks kanban view there is a button "+" (for each stage) to "quick create" a task for a stage. How to make this button open not "a quick create" (small form) but instead open a "Task create" form for that stage? So that when the user clicks "+" on the stage then the user is redirected to the "New task" form (and the stage is preselected). Much like when the user clicks "New" button to create a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This OCA module allow you to open 'New task' form.
https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/10.0/base_optional_quick_create

- go into the menu 'Settings/Technical/Data base structure/ models'
- select the model for which you want to disable the quick create option,
- enable the option Avoid quick create.

It's works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install any new module for this. Add the attribute `quick_create="false"` to kanban. You may remove `on_create` and `quick_create_view` attributes if they exist, but this is not necessary.

```
<kanban quick_create="false" ...>
   ...
   ...
</kanban>
```